# How can I run only ansible tasks with multiple tags?

Tags: ansible

Imagine this ansible playbook:

```
- name: debug foo
  debug: msg=foo
  tags:
     - foo

- name: debug bar
  debug: msg=bar
  tags:
     - bar

- name: debug baz
  debug: msg=baz
  tags:
     - foo
     - bar
```

How can I run only the `debug baz` task? I want to say only run tasks which are tagged with `foo` AND `bar`. Is that possible?

I tried this, but it will run all 3 tasks:

```
ansible-playbook foo.yml -t foo,bar
```

Comment: My only workaround so far has been to use compound tags like `tags: ['foo', 'bar', 'foo-bar']` which is a little ugly... :-(

Comment: This one works like a charm! Thank you very much. Sad, this was not accepted as answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ansible tags use "or" not "and" as a comparison.  Your solution to create yet another tag is the appropriate one.

Answer (score 5):

Try `when` directive:

```
- name: debug foo
  debug: msg=foo
  tags:
     - foo

- name: debug bar
  debug: msg=bar
  tags:
     - bar

- name: debug baz
  debug: msg=baz
  when:
    - '"foo" in ansible_run_tags'
    - '"bar" in ansible_run_tags'
```

Comment: This won't run `baz` if only one tag (`foo` or `bar`) are given. Neither will this run if ansible is called without tags

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. @wolfrevo, that is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to run the task if both `foo`and `bar` are given (i.e. `ansible-playbook foo.yml -t foo,bar`:

```
- debug:
    msg: "(foo and bar)"
  tags:
    - "{{ 'always' if 'foo' in ansible_run_tags and 'bar' in ansible_run_tags else ''}}"
```

If you need it to run either when `foo` or `bar` or both `foo`and `bar` are given (i.e. `ansible-playbook foo.yml -t foo`, `ansible-playbook foo.yml -t bar` or `ansible-playbook foo.yml -t foo,bar`) then use the following:

```
- debug:
    msg: "(foo and bar) or foo or bar"
  tags:
    - "{{ 'always' if 'foo' in ansible_run_tags and 'bar' in ansible_run_tags else ''}}"
    - foo
    - bar
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe the correct syntax is:

```
- name: debug baz
  debug: msg=baz
  tags: foo, bar
```

Comment: sorry the markup was incorrect. It's actually how it would look in the playbook.

Comment: OK, think that's about assigning multiple tags to a single element, but don't think it helps to run only elements which have *multiple* tags...

Comment: Ok, my bad, I misunderstood your question. You can't do this unfortunately via tags. Tags will always run the union of the tags. It will apply them like an OR operator vs an AND operator. So I think Bruce is correct

Answer (score -2):

If you use this way:

```
- name: debug baz
  debug: msg=baz
  tags:
    - foo
    - bar
```

You made a operation OR. So, if you use the command:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory test.yml --tags foo
```

or

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory test.yml --tags bar
```

Will execute this task.

If you use:

```
- name: debug baz
  debug: msg=baz
  tags:
    - foo, bar
```

You made a operation AND. So only the command:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory test.yml --tags foo, bar
```

Will execute this task.

Comment: That does not work. A task defined as in your "AND" example is not executed when called like that.

Comment: If you have a space in between the tags, you need to put the tags in quotes: `--tags "foo, bar"`